# Convert array of objects to an array of the object's values

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am getting a set of data using `getJSON` like this:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/items';
$.getJSON(url, function(response) {
  var response2 = []
  console.log(response)
});
```

My console output is the following:

```
[{"id": 1, "price": 20, "name": "test"}, {"id": 4, "price": 30, "name": "test2"}]
```

I need to convert these values into an array in this format:

```
[[1, 20, "test"], [4, 30, "test2"]]
```

I tried the following code but the result is different:

```
$.each(response, function (key, val) {
  response2.push(val)
});

console.log(response2)  // output = [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do it using `array` here is another way .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var response = [{
  "id": 1,
  "price": 20,
  "name": "test"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "price": 30,
  "name": "test2"
}]
var outerarray = [];
$.each(response, function(key, val) {
  innerarray = []
  innerarray.push(val.id, val.price, val.name) //push value
  outerarray.push(innerarray)
});
console.log(outerarray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry for the "noob" question :)

Answer (score 2):

To do what you require you can use `Object.values` to get the values of all the properties from an object as an array. From there you can use `map()` to build a new array containing them all:

```js
// AJAX response:
let response = [{"id": 1, "price": 20, "name": "test"}, {"id": 4, "price": 30, "name": "test2"}];

let  response2 = response.map(Object.values);
console.log(response2);
```